# Verbose Bibliography style for ConTeXt using numerical indices

Tags: bibliographies, citing, context

I am looking for a verbose bibliography style (one that displays ideally all available information) for ConTeXt that uses numbers for citations and as the index in the listing. The only numbered predefined style, aps, is quite unsuitable for me because it doesn't even display URLs for web documents as a source, just title, author, and year. Now I am using apa and I can get the citations to be numbers (with the `num`option, also the hyperlinks work), but the bibliography itself won't display these numbers, so you can't find the citation reference without clicking on it  in the PDF (I tried `num=yes` but it didn't have an effect).
Now, are there other predefined bibliography styles for context or can I maybe use the ones created for LaTeX? I tried tweaking apa and aps like it is described in the manual but I can't get it to work.

Comment: For a project, I had created a bibliography style follow IEEE bibliography style. It has been almost two years since I last used it, so you might need to tweak a few settings. You can see if it suits your needs. Here is [the file](https://gist.github.com/adityam/afda949f76676055e7906679599ec937)

Comment: Also note that you cannot create a style that displays **all** available information. You can add any field to a bibtex entry (e.g., I can create a field called `abracarabda`. White writing a bibliography style, you need to know the names of the fields that you want to display.

Comment: You're basically asking us to implement a new bibliography style for you.  That is a lot of effort and you can easily do it yourself.  Take the files [`publ-imp-aps.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-aps.lua) and [`publ-imp-aps.mkvi`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-aps.mkvi) as a starting point and extend the style from there.

Comment: @Aditya Please submit this file to Hans for inclusion in core.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I need to test it for completeness and accuracy before it goes into the core.

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks for the links! I did not know that. Is there any more documentation on how to do it? Like why doesn't have Aditya's file a lua complement? And where would I put the files after I created them to use them?

Comment: @DP. Aditya's file doesn't have a Lua complement because he forgot to upload it.   When you have constructed your own bibliography style, just deposit the files in `texmf-local/tex/context/base/mkiv/` and regenerate the filename database.